# Why sequence requires monad if applicative would suffice?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

The signature of sequence is

```
sequence :: Monad m => t (m a) -> m (t a)
```

But we can implement it  as

```
sequence = traverse id
```

requiring `m` to be just `Applicative`. If monads are applicatives then why bother having this constraint on type level?

Comment: Historical reasons.  There's `sequenceA` for the modern haskellista.

Comment: More specifically: it was defined before `Applicative` was known, and later was kept because when `Applicative` was added to `base` it wasn't a superclass of `Monad` yet.

Comment: For some reason, several functions in the past have been generalized to foldables/traversables when those were introduced, yet the previous monad-related functions (`ap`, `sequence`, ...) kept their type even when applicatives were introduced. Such changes are not backward compatible, that's true, but the other generalizations are not backwards compatible as well -- so I'm unsure about the historic reason. (Haskell changed quite a bit: e.g., in the past `Monad` was not even a subclass of `Functor`)

Comment: @chi If `[]` was given a `Foldable` instance when `foldr` was generalized to `(a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`, that's not really a incompatible change, is it? When `Applicative` was introduced, monads didn't immediately become applicatives. Now that `Applicative` *is* a superclass of `Monad`, `sequence` could probably be re-typed. (That said, what's the corner case I'm missing?)

Comment: @chepner It still is incompatible, in the general case, unfortunately. For instance if `class C a where foo :: a` with `instance C [a] where foo = []`, then `length foo` compiles if `length` forces `[a]`, but if `length` only requires a foldable the code is ambiguous. (In GHCi it works only because of `ExtendedDefaultRules`) This is a contrived example, but similar ambiguities can arise in real code.

Comment: I believe, but I can't find the reference right now, that there are certain (quasi-contrived? fully-contrived?) examples where `sequence` can be faster than `sequenceA`.  If anybody can find that explanation (maybe due to Edward Kmett?), I think that would make a great answer.

Comment: Related: [*what does the A stand for in sequenceA?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40181086/2751851)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many functions in Haskell that are equivalent but distinct because `Applicative` (resp. `Functor`) didn’t use to be a superclass of `Monad`. For example:

- `return` vs. `pure`
- `ap` vs. `<*>`
- `liftM` vs. `liftA` vs. `fmap`
- `liftM2`, `liftM3`, &c. vs. `liftA2`, `liftA3`, &c.
- `mapM`/`forM` vs. `traverse`/`for`
- `mapM_`/`forM_` vs. `traverse_`/`for_`
- `sequence` vs. `sequenceA`
- `mzero` & `mplus` (from `MonadPlus`) vs. `empty` & `<|>` (from `Alternative`)

The old functions with their original `Monad` signatures are still present, but in new code, since the [Applicative–Monad Proposal (AMP)](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal) was implemented, you can always use the `Applicative` versions because they’re slightly more general—that is, you can always replace `return` with `pure`, but not vice versa.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "compatibility reasons"? Specifically, what would break if today, `sequence` were changed to have `sequenceA`'s type signature, for example?

Comment: @JosephSible: You know, I may be mistaken—nothing *should* break just from changing the signatures, and there might actually be a plan to do so in the future. It was other changes that didn’t make the cut for AMP, such as moving `join` inside `Monad` and removing `return`, iirc due to issues with the role system.